# Crashing at simple object creation

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
    class SomeClass {
1       String PROXY="localhost:8080";
2       Proxy proxy=new Proxy();
3       proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY);
        // ...
```

At line 3, compiler tells me that object `proxy` does not exist.

How can it not exists when I created it one line above?

---

**Edit:**

I think this won't help, but here is the compiler error(it points to that bracket in line 3.):

> Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Also, ReSharper highlights `proxy`(in line 3) as not found object.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it a `NullReferenceException`? Can you post the full message and stacktrace please?

Comment: He said he gets a compiler error, not a runtime error, but more information is required, can you please post the full compiler error.

Comment: @ojek Based on the error, please post the full class/code you have there. It's likely just a little syntax hiccup somewhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Statements have to go in a method. They can't just be in the body of a type. You've said something like:

```
class P
{
    Foo foo = whatever;
    foo.bar();
}
```

You can put the field declaration outside a method but not the statement. You need to do something like:

```
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = whatever;
        foo.bar();
    }
}
```

All executable code *except for field declarations* has to go in a method in C#.

Make sense?

Comment: To elaborate: In the first example, `foo` was a `private` instance field of the class. In the second example, `foo` was a local variable of the method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear. You have a extra '('

When this happen the IDE sometimes it doesn't mark the exact row.

Check your scopes, maybe it could be a braket or extra parenthesis.